# Stop port 80 on windows server 2008 r2

Tags: windows-server-2008-r2, port80

I have a server application which listening port 80. But when i start listening,i am taking this error :

Error starting listener on port 80: Address already in use: bind

How can i stop port 80 to use it?

Note :  I have stopped "world wide web publishing service"

Answer (score 4, accepted):

"SQL Server Reporting Services" is using port 80. I have stopped it and port 80 is usable now.